# Подскажите пожалуйста как переписать на useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, объекты, декомпиляция

Подскажите пожалуйста как переписать на useState

```
errs.inner.forEach((err: any) => {
  this.setState((state: any) => ({
    fieldsError: {
      ...state.fieldsError,
      [err.path]: err.message,
    },
  }));
});
```

пробовал вот так, но понимаю что это неправильно

```
const [fieldsErrorState, setFieldsErrors] = useState({type: undefined, model: undefined, number: undefined,})


errs.inner.forEach((err: any) => {
  setFieldsErrors({
   ...fieldsErrorState,
   [err.path]: err.message,
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```
errs.inner.forEach((err: any) => {
  setFieldsErrors((prev: any) => ({
    ...prev,
    [err.path]: err.message
  }))
});
```

Comment: Вы правы, но я не понимаю, у меня ведь почти так же, в чем я ошибся?

Comment: Если `setFieldsErrors` вызывается в цикле, то значение `fieldsErrorState` не поменяется, пока цикл не закончится. Поэтому нужно в `setFieldsErrors` явно использовать предыдущее значение.